# Oracle to Azure SQl Server Migration

Tags: azure, oracle11g, azure-sql-database

We are migrating from Oracle to Azure SQL, We are facing issue in modifying user Define type from oracle to sql Server
Below is the error message ::

O2SS0456    User defined types conversion is not supported  O2SS0456: Conversion of 'STRING_AGG_TYPE' failed because user defined type is not supported.

Comment: Seems pretty clear that the conversion tool can't handle some of your custom database objects and code. Some portion of your application will likely have to be redesigned or rebuilt.

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you have already run through [SSMA for Oracle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-oracle-oracletosql?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259view=sql-server-ver15) ?

Did that highlight issues with the UDT?

Comment: yes. Below is the error.." 
 O2SS0456 User defined types conversion is not supported O2SS0456: Conversion of 'STRING_AGG_TYPE' failed because user defined type is not supported."

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE string_agg_type AS OBJECT (

total VARCHAR2 (4000),

STATIC FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize (sctx IN OUT string_agg_type)

RETURN NUMBER,

MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate (

SELF IN OUT string_agg_type,

VALUE IN VARCHAR2

)

RETURN NUMBER,

MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate (

SELF IN string_agg_type,

returnvalue OUT VARCHAR2,

flags IN NUMBER

)

RETURN NUMBER,

MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge (

SELF IN OUT string_agg_type,

ctx2 IN string_agg_type

)

RETURN NUMBER

);

Comment: That pattern is not available in SQL Server. You will likely have to rewrite this finctionality as a .NET CLR function and then build the type from that.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259&view=sql-server-ver15